# How to create a Module for AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, module, appcelerator, titanium-modules, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to develop a custom module for AWS-IOT, [Here](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/3142?restoreSearch=true#!overview)  i got module to access AWS services but the existing module is not supported for AWS-IOT which is the new service launched by Amazon.

I have downloaded the AWS-SDK but here i am unable to find .m files.

Please let me know if you need more info.

Thanks, Rakesh Kalwa.

Answer (score 1):

If AWS marketplace modules is not working then you maybe try another open source module [ti.aws](http://gitt.io/component/ti.aws). please check that.

And if still not working then you can also create your new module based on AWS SDK. for modules development help Please visit  [Extending Titanium Mobile](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Extending_Titanium_Mobile).